# SQL Server Full Text Search: One to many relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, one-to-many

I am trying to retrieve data from tickets that meet search matches. The relevant bits of data here are that a ticket has a **name**, and any number of **comments**.

Currently I'm matching a search against the ticket name like so:

```
JOIN freetexttable(Tickets,TIC_Name,'Test ') s1
    ON TIC_PK = s1.[key]
```

Where the [key] from the full text catalog is equal to TIC_PK.

This works well for me, and gives me access to s1.**rank**, which is **important** for me to sort by.

Now my problem is that this method wont work for ticket searching, because the key in the comment catalog is the comment PK, an doesn't give me any information I can use to link to the ticket.

I'm very perplexed about how to go about searching multiple descriptions and still getting a meaningful **rank**.
I'm pretty knew to full-text search and might be missing something obvious.

Heres my current attempt at getting what I need:

```
WHERE TIC_PK IN(
    SELECT DES_TIC_FK FROM freetexttable(TicketDescriptions, DES_Description,'Test Query') as t
    join TicketDescriptions a on t.[key] = a.DES_PK
    GROUP BY DES_TIC_FK
    )
```

This gets me tickets with comments that match the search, but I dont think it's possible to sort by the rank data freetexttable returns with this method.

Comment: Are you trying to search name + comments in a single search?

Comment: Ideally, but it's the comments that are stumping me, I don't think doing both at the same time would cause any extra issues.

Answer (score 1):

To search the name and comments at the same time and get the most meaningful rank you should put all of this info into the *same table* -- a new table -- populated from your existing tables via an ETL process.

The new table could look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TicketsAndDescriptionsETL (
   TIC_PK int,
   TIC_Name varchar(100),
   All_DES_Descriptions varchar(max),
   PRIMARY KEY (TIC_PK)
)
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON TicketsAndDescriptionsETL (
   TIC_Name LANGUAGE 'English',
   All_DES_Descriptions LANGUAGE 'English'
)
```

Schedule this table to be populated either via a SQL job, triggers on the Tickets and TicketDescriptions tables, or some hook in your data layer. For tickets that have multiple TicketDescriptions records, combine the text of all of those comments into the `All_DES_Descriptions` column.

Then run your full text searches against this new table.

While this approach does add another cog to the machine, there's really no other way to perform full text searches across multiple tables and generate one rank.